# FFmpeg more than 1000 frames duplicated and input height doesn't match

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm currently using this code to record two windows side by side:

```
ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i title="" -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i title="" -c:v h264_nvenc -qp 0 -filter_complex hstack=inputs=2 2.mp4
```

However it throw this error after execution:

```
More than 1000 frames duplicated
```

Error Log: https://pastebin.com/gREVrKVK

The **first window** mostly time is the same frame, maybe 1 frame change in each 3 sec.

Another error in console is when the **first window** have a different height than second window, error:

```
[Parsed_hstack_0 @ 000002491166fd00] Input 1 height 500 does not match input 0 height 488.
[Parsed_hstack_0 @ 000002491166fd00] Failed to configure output pad on Parsed_hstack_0
```

Error log: https://pastebin.com/vqdBPfpv

Looks like is not possible to record when they have different dimensions, so, if possible I would like to ask how to scale the first window to the same **height** (doesn't need to keep aspect ratio) of the second window, considering low CPU use above the video quality.

Comment: See the scale2ref filter, or if you already know the height of the reference video then use the simpler scale filter.

Comment: Could you provide an example? I have tried: `ffmpeg -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i title="" -f gdigrab -framerate 30 -i title="" -c:v h264_nvenc -filter_complex "[0][1]scale2ref[m][i];hstack=inputs=2" 2.mp4` the error was: `Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 0 on filter Parsed_hstack_1` and what about the message of 1000 duplicated frames?

Comment: You should not be asking two questions in one post. (Although if you need to prioritise CPU usage when recording, why not mux the two screengrabs as separate video streams and ‘fix it in post’?)

Comment: I'm not asking two questions, i said it throw two different errors, and please stop saying why you don't this or that, i have found the code above while searching here in Stack, i have no knowledge in FFmpeg.

Answer (score 7):

## Question 1: How to match input heights?

[image] [image]
<sub>Original images</sub>

### scale2ref

[image]

Make `input0` height match `input1` height with the [scale2ref](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#scale2ref) filter:

```
ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -filter_complex "[0][1]scale2ref=w=oh*mdar:h=ih[left][right];[left][right]hstack" output
```

### Fit into specific size

[image]

Make each input fit into 175x100 with gray background:

```
ffmpeg -i input0 -i input1 -filter_complex "[0]scale=175:100:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=175:100:-1:-1:color=gray,setsar=1[left];[1]scale=175:100:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=175:100:-1:-1:color=gray,setsar=1[right];[left][right]hstack" output
```

More examples: [Resizing videos with ffmpeg to fit into static size](https://superuser.com/a/1136305).

---

## Question 2: More than 1000 frames duplicated

Refer to the warning in your log:

```
[mp4 @ 0000026082276400] Frame rate very high for a muxer not efficiently supporting it.
Please consider specifying a lower framerate, a different muxer or -vsync 2
```

Add the `-vsync 2` output option, or output to a different format such as `.mkv`.

Comment: Thank you, what about when its 3 or more windows? I have tried editing your code adding one more window, but it keep trowing a lot of messages about `Invalid DTS` in the console, follow the log: https://pastebin.com/7w4x8HXc

Comment: @Karine Does the output look ok?

Comment: You mean if its recording correctly all windows? It does, but the entire time it throw this message in the console. I also noticed the file being saved so huge, is it normal? around 600mb in 10min

Comment: @Karine Just ignore the warnings if the output looks ok. File size is normal. h264_nvenc is less efficient than libx264 so h264_nvenc makes bigger file sizes than libx264. You did not add a rate control method so it is using the defaults which may not be what you want. See https://superuser.com/a/1296511 for suggestions for h264_nvenc.

Comment: I think the spam of these messages `Invalid DTS` in the console is causing a high use of CPU, do you know if there's any option to suppress error/warnings?

Comment: @Karine Should be asked as a new question. This Q/A is mostly about *How to match input heights?*. You are expected to ask 1 question per post at Stack Overflow.

Comment: At what part of the full command should we put -vsync 2 option? I am not getting it, should I put it before the output file name?